# How to pass data from page to page

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, ionic2

My objective is to pass data from page to page.  However this error is bugging me. i have declare the navCtrl at the constructor

My constructor for request.ts

```
 constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, angFire: AngularFireDatabase) {
    this.request = angFire.list('/request');
    this.userreq = angFire.list(`${this.userkey}`);
    this.reqdetails = angFire.list('reqdetails');

  }
```

my html page for request.html

```
<button class="nearby" ion-button large (click)="openMapPage()">Nearby</button>
```

my OpenPage method for request.ts

```
openMapPage()
  {

  var ref = firebase.database().ref("request");
    ref.once("value")
  .then(function(snapshot) {
    var a = snapshot.exists();  // true
    var c = snapshot.hasChild("reqdetails"); // true

    var d = snapshot.child('reqdetails').exists();
    var requestsKey = snapshot.key;
    var requestsValue = snapshot.val();


   snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
        var requestKey = childSnapshot.key;
        var requestValue = childSnapshot.val();

        var reqdetails = requestValue.reqdetails;

       if(reqdetails)
       {
        this.data = requestKey;
        console.log(this.data);
        //this.arr.push(requestKey);
        //console.log(this.arr);
       }

    });
       this.navCtrl.push(MapPage, {'param1':this.data});

});   



}
```

So after the user clicks on the OpenMapPage() from the request.html it will go to the openMapPage method found in reqeuest.ts and it will render the data to the map.html page

my map.html page:

```
<ion-list>
  <ion-card *ngFor="let user of request | async" class="job">

    <ion-avatar class="avatar" item-start>
        <img src="../assets/icon/user_male-512.png">
    </ion-avatar>
    <h2 class="name">{{user.regdetails.username}}</h2>
    <p text-wrap class="address"><ion-icon name="compass"></ion-icon> {{user.regdetails.address}}</p>
    <p id="key">{{user.$key}}</p>
     </button> 
  </ion-card>
</ion-list>
```

Now the error i am getting is this:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use **[Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)**. By using arrow functions, the `this` property is not overwritten and still references the component instance (otherwise, the this keyword points to the inner function, and your component's methods and variables are not defined in it):

```
openMapPage() {

    var ref = firebase.database().ref("request");
    ref.once("value").then((snapshot) => { // <------ Here!
        var a = snapshot.exists();  // true
        var c = snapshot.hasChild("reqdetails"); // true
        var d = snapshot.child('reqdetails').exists();
        var requestsKey = snapshot.key;
        var requestsValue = snapshot.val();

        snapshot.forEach((childSnapshot) => { // <------ And here!
            var requestKey = childSnapshot.key;
            var requestValue = childSnapshot.val();

            var reqdetails = requestValue.reqdetails;

            if (reqdetails) {
                this.data = requestKey;
                console.log(this.data);
                //this.arr.push(requestKey);
                //console.log(this.arr);
            }

        });

        this.navCtrl.push(MapPage, { 'param1': this.data });
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: Glad to help :)

Answer (score 1):

You are using a regular function as a callback in `snapshot.forEach`.

Use arrow function so that `this` will refer to the class object *or* use a temporary variable to save `this` before the call.

```
snapshot.forEach((childSnapshot) => {
        var requestKey = childSnapshot.key;
        var requestValue = childSnapshot.val();

        var reqdetails = requestValue.reqdetails;

       if(reqdetails)
       {
        this.data = requestKey;
        console.log(this.data);
        //this.arr.push(requestKey);
        //console.log(this.arr);
       }

    });
```

Note: Also use arrow function in the outer callback

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: Oh, seems like we answered the question at the same time... I'm sorry :)

Comment: i can only give 1 person the tick